# How to set user input as a variable for if statement

Tags: python-3.x

How do you set user input to a variable in order to use 'if' statement effectively? My code seems to disregard the user's input (yes, no and even other) and defaults to the user's input being yes.

```
input("...? ")
yes = True
no = False
if yes:
    print("...")
if no:
   print("...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` is a function that returns the user input as a string, which you can save to a variable. Your code defaults to yes because you set `yes = True`, so it always enters the first condition.

```py
inp = input("...?")  # save user input in the variable `inp`
if inp == "yes":
    ...
elif inp == "no":
    ...
else:
    ...
```